# Equation error in Latex table

Tags: latex, equation

I'd like to create a table with two parameters and the corresponding equation.
Somehow Latex gives me the error:

> '! Missing $ inserted.'

and I don't know what that means...

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{XXX}
\label{tab:XXX}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline\hline
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Parameter & Mathematical Equation \\    \hline 
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Standard Deviation & \sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sum(X-\mu)$^2$}{N}} \\
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Variance & \sigma^2=\frac{\sum(X-\mu)$^2$}}{N} \\
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TeX, `$` signs enclose inline math code [(see here)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments). Your example already uses it around `^2`. However, you also use other macros that are only valid inside a math environment, such as e.g. `\sigma`. Hence, you should surround *all* macros that require math mode with `$` signs:

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{XXX}
\label{tab:XXX}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline\hline
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Parameter & Mathematical Equation \\    \hline 
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Standard Deviation & $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{\sum(X-\mu)^2}{N}}$ \\
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    Variance & $\sigma^2=\frac{\sum(X-\mu)^2}{N}$ \\
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

If you prefer not to mix TeX and LaTeX commands, consider using `\(...\)` instead of `$...$`.